# Display image or video from source in react when source is random

Tags: reactjs, image, canvas, video, ipfs

I'm pulling certain assets from an api but the issue is that the assets contain image, video and canvas therefore the source type is random, I want to display all of them on a page but the source link doesn't have a mimetype it's just an ipfs hash so can't differentiate on basis of that.

Is there a way to display image and if image is broken display with video tag and if its broken display with canvas tag?

Example for video -> https://infura-ipfs.io/ipfs/QmVSCZfGc5ArLSzra2A5yTrwASaM92sdWGj4ovZuiLTG6f

Example for canvas -> https://infura-ipfs.io/ipfs/QmSD9GfNwAtBH6WVUEhfK7wX6vFbsUqRzupqjD25Pn2RQV

Answer (score 1):

bro you can do it specifying meta data image as thumbnail and in detail page you can use if the video property is present you can show video if not or undefined go with image like

```
const [video,setVideo]=useState(false)
const [image,SetImage]=useState(false)
async function(){
let metadata=axios.get(uri)
if(metadat.video !=undefined){
  setVideo(true)
}
else{
SetImage(true)
}
 }

{video &&  <video source=""></video>}
{image &&  <img src=""/>}
```

its just an example you I hope you will be able to modify